# why "pick property " in advanced search does not work properly

Tags: search, enterprise-search

I have serveral pages in Page library, one of them has its properties as below:

```
title: pagecontent1
createdBy: system account (login name: mylen123)
```

I first tried searching with ***The exact phrase***,  by keyword **"pagecontent1"**. SharePoint search returned 2 results, one is the `pagecontent1.aspx` itself, and the second is `AllItems.aspx` of Page library. It seemd the result made sense and worked properly.

However, when I was trying doing so with **pick property**, it did not work, returning 0 result. In detail, I chose **"where the property is " + Author + Contains "system"**. I think, i should return 2 results as the first try since those pages are both created by "system admin".

I also go to search service application to check out Managed Properties (MP) to see that whether CreatedBy MP is mapped with corresponding `ows_Created_x0020_By` Crawled Properties (CP).

Why this search option does not work? Could you tell me how to make SP search effectively?